# Trying to invert a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am currently trying to invert a table consisting of the following code:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in dataStuff.data track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="y in x track by $index">
            y: {{y}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I cannot figure out if there is a simple way to invert this table, or if I will have to write a function in JavaScript to rearrange the data.

Comment: Those `ng-repeat`s are going to really work your `$digest` cycles depending on how much data you have...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "invert"?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want that one condition displayed simplest is to just reverse the array in controller before passing to view using [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

```
$scope.dataStuff.data.reverse()
```